# how to insert values of datagridview rows by column in database c#

Tags: c#, sql, loops, datagridview

I have used a function for inserting textboxes values in datagridview, now I want to insert the datagridview rows by column in database on button click and I am trying for that this code:

```
for (int RowIndex = 0; RowIndex < dgViewMedicines.Rows.Count; RowIndex++)
            {
            int Presc_Id = Convert.ToInt32(LPresc_ID);
            PID = Convert.ToInt32(tbPID.Text);
            Med_Id = 
Convert.ToInt32(dgViewMedicines.Rows[RowIndex].Cells["MedID"].Value);
            Med_Time = (dgViewMedicines.Rows[RowIndex].Cells["MedTime"].ToString());
            Med_Duration = (dgViewMedicines.Rows[RowIndex].Cells["MedDuration"].ToString());
            Med_QTY = Convert.ToInt32(dgViewMedicines.Rows[RowIndex].Cells["MedQTY"].Value);

            string query2 = "INSERT INTO tblPrescDetailMedicine Values ('"+ Presc_Id +"', '"+ PID +"', '"+ Med_Id +"', '"+ Med_Time +"', '"+ Med_Duration +"', '"+ Med_QTY +"')";

            cmd.CommandText = query2;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am getting the values from the first two commands, but not getting values from other commands, like if I run the application, enters the data and try to save data by clicking the button, I receive an error called "Input string was not in a correct" on the third command.

Please have a look on to this and let me know where is the problem actually. I will be very thank ful to you .

Comment: That is absolutely the wrong way to create a query.  If you have a DataGridView, the easiest way to insert to a DB - it takes almost no code - is to use a DataTable and a DataAdapter.

Comment: Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp can you please give me a short code for an example for that? Please I am just a beginner at c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong but as far as I am aware DataGridView Cells require an Index number, which makes sense why you would be getting an error on the third line in the loop, see if this works:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgViewMedicines.Rows)
{
    int Presc_Id = (int)LPresc_ID;
    PID = (int)tbPID.Text;
    Med_Id = (int)r.Cells[0].Value;
    Med_Time = (string)r.Cells[1];
    Med_Duration = (string)r.Cells[2];
    Med_QTY = (int)r.Cells[3].Value;

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblPrescDetailMedicine Values ('"+ Presc_Id +"', '"+ PID +"', '"+ Med_Id +"', '"+ Med_Time +"', '"+ Med_Duration +"', '"+ Med_QTY +"')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, it works. Also can you please tell me that what is the difference between for loop and foreach loop?

Comment: A foreach loop simply loops through every instances in an Object. The for loop you used is perfectly fine and also allows you to have a count of the amount of instances you rotate through, however in your case it isn't necerssary. For your scenario it is easier to simply loop through each row within the DatGridView.

Answer (score 0):

```
string db="";
string databaseError="Error while locating".Count()>Convert.ToPDF(beaver.Text).ToString();
if(databaseError!=databaseError+beaver.Text.toInt32())
{
HttpWeb http = new HttpWeb(beaver.addText("host=");
http.LoadDatabase(query.Select().For(int i=0; i<100); i++)
{
while(1==1)
{
Database.query="select * from * where * = 1");
Database.query="update * set * = beaver.Text);
// Print recipe for cake from database error login sign up error enterprise edition 2019 full
MessageBox.Show(error.databaseError);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Hey Rick Astley, I could not understand what you've commented. Is it related to my problem? I think its not.